# Fastest way to join 2 lists?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm making a program and in a very specific part I need to join 2 lists of objects. I've always used append to do such things but I've read that append it's not that fast. These two lists I need to join will eventually grow. So I'm looking for the fastest way *for the computer* to do it.

Should I use

```
(append list1 list2)
```

Or better:

```
(foldr cons list1 list2)
```

I do not think I mind about the order of the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be slightly faster for lists of equal length:

```
(foldl cons list1 list2)
```

Why? because it starts `cons`ing elements from `list2` at the *head* of `list1`, whereas `append` will first `cons` all of the elements of `list1` before `cons`ing `list2` at the end - and notice that I'm using `foldl`, not `foldr`. That'll have the benefit of running in constant space (because of tail-recursion).

To put it another way: the `foldl` solution runs in constant space and is `O(length-of-list2)` whereas the `append` solution is `O(length-of-list1)` and doesn't run in constant space, bear that in mind if the lists have different lengths.

Comment: `append` is not O(sum of lengths). It's O(sum of lengths but the last list) since it shares structure. It might happen that `foldr` and `append` are not written tail recursive modulo cons and in that case using `foldl` would use constant stack but otherwise big O is the same.

Comment: `(foldl cons x y)` is the same as `(append-reverse y x)`. The latter, I hope, is more intuitively-named. :-)

Comment: Then, if the big O is the same...it doesn't matter which I use?

Comment: @DavidMerinos `foldl` will use less space. And although the big O is the same, the `n` in `O(n)` depends on which option you choose, as mentioned in the last paragraph.